# Template non-type member function pointer argument deduction error in Visual C++

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

Consider the following code:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void foo() {}
    void foo(double d) {}
};


template <typename Fun>
void bar_simple(Fun fun) {}

template <typename Base>
struct Wrapper {
    template <typename Type>
    static void bar(Type Base::* fun) {}
};

template <typename Type, typename Base>
void bar(Type Base::* fun) {}


int main() {
    //ok
    bar_simple<void(Foo::*)()>(&Foo::foo);
    bar_simple<void(Foo::*)(double)>(&Foo::foo);

    //ok
    Wrapper<Foo>::bar<void()>(&Foo::foo);
    Wrapper<Foo>::bar<void(double)>(&Foo::foo);

    //yields: error C2784: 'void bar(Type Base::* )' : 
    //could not deduce template argument for 'overloaded function type' 
    //from 'overloaded function type'; see declaration of 'bar'
    bar<void()>(&Foo::foo);
    bar<void(double)>(&Foo::foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Above code compiles on gcc-4.3.4 and comeau 4.3.10.1, and fails on both Visual C++ 9.0 and 10.0.
This seems like a bug; are you aware of existence of appropriate bug report in MS's "bug tracker"?

Comment: +1 looks like bug. just report it.

Comment: can someone verify this on Visual C++ 11.0? Bug reporting for older versions of MS's compiler seems to be unsupported.

Comment: done, (http://pastebin.com/JrDGqwW1).

Comment: thanks, I am creating a bug report then